# Folder structure or database structure for creating/editing 'files'?

Tags: c#, architecture, sql-server, directory-structure

As a hobby experiment I am creating a on-line tool for creating web sites with the ability to create custom HTML and CSS using a template engine for safe-use of functionality.

Now I am in the dilemma if I should save the template files in a "customers" folder, and create a tree view of this file structure - or if I should go for adding a new row in the database containing the mark-up and build a tree view from the table?

I will be doing revisions of the file changes, so i am moving more and more towards having the "files" (meta-data) stored in the database, instead of real files on the server, and just glue the pieces together in the presentation layer.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952/storing-a-file-in-a-database-as-opposed-to-the-file-system

Answer (score 3):

I always prefer files for this purpose, simply because it makes the design easier for others to reuse and test:

- There is no need to install or maintain a database.
- You can clone or move your "database" simply by cloning or moving the file system.